# Assimp Sample giving errors

Tags: c++, opengl, assimp

I just got the last assimp SDK, and made a project, I linked it corectly ( no errors with linking ) But I seem to have some troubles with the Sample project. To be more specific the SimpleOpenGL one.
I am using C++ combined with OpenGL and visual studio 10.

```
struct aiVector3D scene_min, scene_max, scene_center;
```

The line above creates the following errors.

```
1>main.cpp(25): error C2371: 'aiVector3D' : redefinition; different basic types
1>d:\libraries\assimp--3.0.1270-sdk\include\assimp\vector3.h(124) : see declaration of 'aiVector3D'
1>main.cpp(25): error C2079: 'scene_min' uses undefined struct 'aiVector3D'
1>main.cpp(25): error C2079: 'scene_max' uses undefined struct 'aiVector3D'
1>main.cpp(25): error C2079: 'scene_center' uses undefined struct 'aiVector3D'
```

There are more errors but I will post them if they still appear after I solve this one.

***Edit due to comment***

Looks like that works! Thnx. But could you explain why the word struct wouldn't affect the program in C?

Comment: I summed my comments up in an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove the word `struct` from your definitions because `aiVector3D` is differently declared [in the header file](https://github.com/assimp/assimp/blob/master/include/assimp/vector3.h).

In the linked header file you see the line `#ifdef __cplusplus` which is used by the preprocessor for conditional compilation. This means that everything until the next `#else` will be compiled into the object file if you use a C++ compiler. And this code tells us that aiVector3D is a typedef (= other name) for `aiVector3t<float>`.

If you use a plain C compiler the declaration of aiVector3D is

```
struct aiVector3D {
    float x,y,z;
}
```

and this would fit your defintions.

Comment: Thnx a lot :) Did not looked carefully in those files :(